# Too much time take to create site columns for a content type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, load-balancing, content-type, site-column

We are working on creating site columns for a content type. But we are faced with an issue where the screen 'Working on it. This shouldn't take too long' is freezed for hours together. We have close to 1000 subsites that inherit this content type. Why are we facing this issue?

**Details**-
SharePoint 2013 with
2 App servers 2 WFE servers

Comment: Also its difficult to verify whether the site column has been added on all the subsites.

Comment: This would be a better question for [sharepoint.se]